# Same random numbers every loop iteration

Tags: c++, random, for-loop

I have a `for` loop that runs 15 times, with `dh.setDoors()` in every iteration.

What `setDoors` does is call `srand(time(0))`, then whenever a random number is needed it'll use, for example, `carSetter = rand()%3+1`. Alternatively, it may use `decider = rand()%2+1`.

Now, normally `decider` and `carSetter` are used in a different ways, but I suspected a problem and made it print out `carSetter` and `decider` at every iteration. Here's what came out:

```
Door 1 has car
Decider is 2
Door 1 has car
Decider is 2
Door 1 has car
Decider is 2
Door 1 has car
Decider is 2
Door 1 has car
Decider is 2
etc...
```

The values '1' and '2' change when I run it multiple times, but are still the same throughout the 15 times.

Since the loop is running 15 different times, shouldn't `carSetter` and `decider` print out a different random number every iteration?

When I don't have `srand(time(0))`, it works as expected, but there's no seed set, so it's the same sequence of "random" numbers each time, so it's probably a problem with the seed?

Comment: Seeding should be done *once*, ever. Read up on how pseudo-random number generators work, and it's probably good to learn some probability theory too while you're at it.

Comment: I'm only using srand once in setDoors, setDoors is just being repeated 15 times. Is the problem that srand is being repeated 15 times?

Comment: It would be easier to describe the solution when you *post your actual code*.

Comment: @GlassZee: Yes. As Kerrek already said, you should do `srand` once in your program.

Comment: @GregHewgill: ... that is, the _actual_ complete minimal testcase that the OP is debugging with.

Comment: A comment on style: You're using `0` as a pointer value in `time(0)`. In modern C++, especially with C++11 it's a bad idea to use `0` as a pointer. Use `nullptr` if the compilers you're targeting support it: `srand(time(nullptr))`. If the compiler doesn't support `nullptr` then `NULL` is at least a small improvement over `0`. Also the `<random>` library is great, though it may be a bit beyond a first-week student.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `srand(x)`, then the value of `x` determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers returned in following calls to `rand()`, *depending entirely on the value of `x`*.

When you're in a loop and call `srand()` at the top:

```
while (...) {
    srand(time(0));
    x = rand();
    y = rand();
}
```

then the *same* random number sequence is generated depending on the value that `time(0)` returns. Since computers are fast and your loop probably runs in less than a second, `time(0)` returns the *same* value each time through the loop. So `x` and `y` will be the same each iteration.

Instead, you only usually need to call `srand()` *once* at the start of your program:

```
srand(time(0));

while (...) {
    x = rand();
    y = rand();
}
```

In the above case, `x` and `y` will have different values each time through the loop.

Comment: *Put on my blue psuedo shoes...*

Answer (score 3):

Every time you invoke `srand(time(0))`, you're *seeding* the pseudo-random number generator, imbuing it with a new pseudo-random sequence of numbers. The sequence is different depending on what the argument to `srand` is, and in this instance you use `time(0)` so, assuming you call your program at most once per second, you'll always get a new sequence. When you call `rand()`, you just get the next number in this sequence.

However, since you've decided to call `srand` multiple times in your program, and because your program is fast (i.e. `time(0)` isn't changing), all you're doing is repeatedly resetting the PRNG to the same sequence. That's why you're always getting the same values - you keep reseeding the PRNG to be the same sequence, and this also moves the cursor to the beginning of the sequence.

**Seed once. Once.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `srand` in the beginning of your program, for example in the `main`-function.

When you run `srand(time(0))` at the top of the function in which you are using `rand()`, you are likely to give it the same seed every time. `time(0)` gives the time in seconds, so you would need to avoid calling `setDoors` twice within the same second in order to get different numbers every time. If you *do* call `setDoors` twice within the same second, the random seed will be the same, and subsequent calls to `rand()` will generate the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Like Kerrek said, seeding is done only once, in the beginning of the program. After one srand call rand as many times as you like.