# Same random numbers

Tags: c++, random, srand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Same random numbers every loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251117/same-random-numbers-every-loop-iteration)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int attack() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int hits=0;
    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
        int a = rand() % 6;
        if (a==6 || a==5)
        {
         hits++;   
        }
    }
    return hits;
}

int main () {
    int a=attack();
    cout << a << endl;
    int b=attack();
        cout << b << endl;
    int c=attack();
        cout << c << endl;
    int d=attack();
        cout << d << endl;
    int e=attack();
        cout << e << endl;
    int f=attack();
        cout << f << endl;
    int g=attack();
        cout << g << endl;
    int h=attack();
        cout << h << endl;
}
```

why are all my variables in `main()` the same number?

I only get outputs like this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: You should only initialize (`srand`) once (in the *whole program* unless you know what you are doing and why) and `a = rand() % 6;` will never return 6 (but will return 0). For details read the documentation. I, know. I know: last resort. But you have to do it. You really do.

Comment: Another question that could have been avoided by [reading the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand)...

Comment: Another comment that could have been avoided...well...just avoided...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`srand()` should be called *once* at the start of the program (well, at some point before you start calling `rand()` anyway).

By calling it every time you enter the function (in quick succession), you're resetting the seed value to the same thing, which is why you're seeing duplicate numbers.

Note that you *may* occasionally get a different number if the time clicks over to a new second while your program is running, but it's not that likely since that particular program should finish in far less than one second.

Move the `srand()` call to `main()` before the first call to `attack()`.