# rand() is consistent across multiple function calls

Tags: c, function, random, time, random-seed

When I try to generate 2 random numbers from within a function call, I'm getting repeated results.

However, the `rand()` function works fine in loops or whatnot provided they are outside of function calls.

I'm guessing that it is because of the system time and that program is small. But I do not know how else to vary the seed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int test1(){

    int randX, randY;
    int range = 5;

    srand( time(NULL) );

    randX = (rand() % range) + 1; 

    randY = (rand() % 15   ) + 1;
    printf("X:%d  Y:%d\n", randX, randY);
}

int main(){

    test1();
    test1();
    test1();
    test1();
    test1();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same random numbers every loop iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251117/same-random-numbers-every-loop-iteration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you call

```
srand( time(NULL) );
```

every time you use the function. Its granularity is one second, so If you call it twice within a very short time interval, you will seed the random number generator with the same value - unless the clock happens to tick *just between* the two calls.

You should call `srand()` *once* at the start of your program.

Answer (score 4):

As per `C11` standard document, chapter 7.22.2.2, `srand()` function,

> The `srand()` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand()`. If `srand()` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.

So, the issue with your code is you're calling `srand( time(NULL) );` inside the `test1()` function. Effectively, you're seeding the pseudo-random number generator every time while calling the `test()` function. Now, the `time(NULL)` will return the same value for a whole second, i.e, it is having the time granularity of 1 second. So, successive calls to `test()` function **within that granularity period** (of 1 second) will cause

- PRNG to be *re-seeded* with the *same* value
- successive calls to `rand()` will produce the same set of *random* numbers.

Solution: You need to call `srand( time(NULL) );` only once from `main()`.

That said, two more important things to mention,

1. You're missing the required header files. For `rand()` and `srand()` you need to have `stdlib.h`, for `time()` include `time.h`.
2. Your `int test1()` function is declared to have a return value of type `int`, while your function does not have any `return` statement. It is acceptable if the returned value is not used in caller, but if in case the returned value is used, it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So better consider adding a `return` value in `test()` or change the return type to `void`.

Sidenote:

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)` (in this case).
2. It is considered to be a good practice to add an explicit `return` value, though not mandatory in case of `main()`.

Comment: `time` will return the same value for a whole second. So repeated seeding (which does not make much sense in the first place) would only work with long pauses in between.