# C random number generator generate sometimes the same numbers

Tags: c, random

i have strange behavior in which i try to generate random numbers 
and they sometimes totally the same ,
 or there is problem if they created on the same time?
using VC 2012

```
for (int i = array_size; i < (array_size); i++)
{

        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        int rw = rand() % 960 + (20); //returns a pseudo-random integer between x resolution size 0 -> width
        int rh = rand() % 640 + (20);    //returns a pseudo-random integer between x resolution size 0 -> height
        lwsl_notice("c:%d width %d height %d\n",c, rw, rh);
        c++;
}
```

The output is :

```
[2016/06/30 09:39:09:7274] NOTICE: c:0 width 606 height 567
[2016/06/30 09:39:09:7274] NOTICE: c:1 width 606 height 567
[2016/06/30 09:39:09:7274] NOTICE: c:2 width 606 height 567
[2016/06/30 09:39:09:7274] NOTICE: c:3 width 606 height 567
```

Comment: You should use `srand` outside the loop and once.

Comment: oops the more correct dup is [Same random numbers every loop iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9251117/995714), [rand() is consistent across multiple function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29478555/995714), [srand(time(NULL)) doesn't change seed value quick enough](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5574914/995714), [srand() — why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is so fast that `time(NULL)` always have the same value. This means that your generator always starts from the same seed, so it will always generate the exact same values.

`srand` should be called once and only once in your program (outside the `for` loop). Commonly, people call it once from the`main` function.

Answer (score 5):

Move `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));` out of the `for` loop.

Comment: This is the correct answer but you should explain why that's the case.

Comment: It would be useful to tell explain where exactly can srand be called and what are the pros and cons of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Inside for loop you initialized **i** as `array_size` and you are looping it till `i<array_size` with incrementing **i**. Whats that? Please post some more code.

Comment: That's not an answer

Comment: it's **without** incrementing `i` and the loop won't execute a single time. Anyway that's not the main problem here because even if the OP fixes the loop it won't work anyway