# Random number generator generating the same number even after seeding

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int RandomIntGen(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "I am rolling a " << RandomIntGen(1, 6) << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}

// A random integer generator that takes in a upper and lower integer limit and returns a random integer
int RandomIntGen(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0)); //seeding with time
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randomInteger(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    return randomInteger(randomGenerator);
}
```

Don't know why it's generating the same value even with seeding. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to seed it only once, when you seed you reset sequence

Comment: what seed do you use when you first call the function? and what seed do you use when you call it for the second time? Hint: usually prngs produce the exact same sequence when seeded with the same seed

Comment: `time()` usually has a resolution of 1 second, so it's normal that you get the same result every time you call your function again within that same second. Just seed once.

Comment: Should I just seed once in main() or put "default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));" in global space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same random numbers every loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251117/same-random-numbers-every-loop-iteration)

Comment: I think you `default_random_engine` doesn't affect `uniform_int_distribution<int>`, that means that your uniform_int_distribution isn't affected by seeding, so it is always the same value

Answer (score 1):

Moved "default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));" to global space to make sure it is seeded only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//Random Generator with Seed
default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));

// Function Declarations
int RandomIntGen(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "I am rolling a " << RandomIntGen(1, 6) << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}

// A random integer generator that takes in a upper and lower integer limit and returns a random integer
int RandomIntGen(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randomInteger(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    return randomInteger(randomGenerator);
}
```